# Raspberry Pi Two USB Serial Lag

Tags: python, pyserial

I have two serial USB inputs connected to my Rbpi. I am using Python's Pyserial. One device is being read at 9600 and the other at 57600

For some reason, there is a lag in data for the 57600 serial input. It takes about 2s to come in, and this only happens when the other one is enabled. I am reading string data:

```
self.ser = serial.Serial(strPort, 57600)
self.ser2 = serial.Serial(strPort, 9600)
line = self.ser.readline()
line2 = self.ser2.readline()
```

I have also tried splitting them into two processes. It is still too slow

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue to me. Your two USB interfaces may be sharing the same bus.

Comment: Could be worth asking/searching on RaspberryPi.SE

Comment: Actually, there is this 2-3s delay each time. According to this,
http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/unexpected-long-pyserial-read-delay-on-windows.671839/

there might be some issue with FIFO